# MongoDB server crashing on Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, google-compute-engine

I have setup MongoDB on GCE Instance and have created PHP API's to access this database from website's servers (different instances).

The problem is, when there is traffic on my website (say about 100 users) and users access data from MongoDB, the GCE CPU usage starts increasing and ultimately it goes to 100% usage and the server stops responding.

At that moment i checked number of active connections on MongoDB and they were around 100 of the available 50,000.

I ran the following command to check which top 5 processes are using the server:

```
watch "ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5"
```

It shows the following result:

```
mongodb    392  6.7 19.6 1046868 745224 ?      Sl   Nov04  43:26 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
www-data 18649  0.0  0.2 283300 10392 ?        S    05:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18648  0.0  0.2 283300 10392 ?        S    05:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18647  0.0  0.2 283300 10392 ?        S    05:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18646  0.0  0.2 283300 10392 ?        S    05:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I enabled server-status on Apache and it is showing that cpu usage is only 0.00236%

Can any one please help me where the problem can be and what process should i monitor to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The process table you posted shows normal cpu and ram usage for apache and mongodb.

You can use a monitoring script which runs from cron job and checks cpu and memory. The script can  send you an email with stats, if the resource usage is higher than expected. See: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/monitoring/get-system-information-in-html-format/ and https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/processing-the-delimited-files-using-cut-and-awk.html

Comment: You can use [stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) to monitor the CPU usage of your GCE instance and setup alerts. Also, you can use [stackdriver MongoDB](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/mongodb) plugin to monitor the status of your cluster.